# Custom module for adding custom template on admin cms page

Tags: php, magento

I want to make a custom module for magento admin cms page.

So for this module which classes I have to use and which folder will be created..?

What I want to do in this module that first of all I have to create a some predefined templates for admin in which some images and text can be putted, the list of these template should be available at the page creation time. when I select a template from predefined template list then its form will be opened and then I can insert images and text in it and after saving this block, the content of this template should be shown on that page after page content on frontend.?

If someone got what I want in above module then please guide me. I have some basic knowledge of making custom module in magento.

Comment: Don't have exact idea but this might help u. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-module-creator.html

Comment: I think u can achieve this by creating custom variables in magento. Just create custom variable with predefined image and other HTML code. u can use WYSIWYG editor for this too.

then just add this variable in ur static block or cms page or in ur transactional mail.

Read below link.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-custom-variables

Comment: Thanks for reply @Niraj. But in my template file I am using PHP code also. So how can I put them in custom variables in magento.?